# JavaScript: Creating a simple number guessing game and getting an Uncaught Type Error

Tags: javascript

i am trying to create a number guessing game in javascript and the game is working except for the user selects a number that is less than the value of the "mysterNumber".

The error is get in the console is:

```
scripts.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null(…)
playGame @ scripts.js:28
clickHandler @ scripts.js:17
```

Here is the HTML

```js
    // Game variables 
    var mysteryNumber = 50;
    var playerGuess = 0;
    
    // The input and output fields
    var input = document.querySelector("#input");
    var ouput = document.querySelector("#ouput");
    
    // The button 
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    
    button.style.cursor = "pointer";
    
    button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
    
    function clickHandler(){
     playGame();
    }
    
    function playGame(){
     playersGuess = parseInt(input.value);
    
     if(playersGuess > mysteryNumber){
      output.innerHTML = "That's too high."
     }else if(playersGuess < mysteryNumber){
      ouput.innerHTML = "That's too low."
     }else if(playersGuess === mysteryNumber){
      output.innerHTML = "You got it!"
     }
    }
```

```html
<p id="output">I am thinking of a number between 0 and 99.</p>
    <input id ="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your guess...">
    <button>guess</button>
```

Comment: You are in unique position of being able to show us exactly what your problem is. Use "JavaScript/HTML/CSS Snippet" button of your question editor to create a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several typos in your code.  Make sure you're consistently using "output" instead of "ouput".

Answer (score 0):

As @Igor mentioned, you can create a snippet as part of your question, I did that for you and the answer became easier to spot. @msidak said it was spelling errors and sure enough, you code only failed when the guess was too low and there you had spelled "output" as "ouput".

When you want to accept the best answer I suggest @msidak, he got it right first I was just bored enough to put it all together

```js
    // Game variables 
    var mysteryNumber = 50;
    var playerGuess = 0;
    
    // The input and output fields
    var input = document.querySelector("#input");
    var ouput = document.querySelector("#ouput");
    
    // The button 
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    
    button.style.cursor = "pointer";
    
    button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
    
    function clickHandler(){
     playGame();
    }
    
    function playGame(){
     playersGuess = parseInt(input.value);
    
     if(playersGuess > mysteryNumber){
      output.innerHTML = "That's too high."
     }else if(playersGuess < mysteryNumber){
      output.innerHTML = "That's too low."
     }else if(playersGuess === mysteryNumber){
      output.innerHTML = "You got it!"
     }
    }
```

```html
<p id="output">I am thinking of a number between 0 and 99.</p>
    <input id ="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your guess...">
    <button>guess</button>
```